# Error getRoutePointsForRoute

Tags: android, skmaps

After i drawn the route, i want to get the points of the route using the function getRoutePointsforRoute in the class SKRouteManager of SKOBBLER. The function returns a list of SKCoordinates but they are all zeros.

```
public void onAllRoutesCompleted() {
    List<SKCoordinate> list_coordinates = SKRouteManager.getInstance().getRoutePointsForRoute(idRoute);
    for(int i=0; i< list_coordinates.size();i++)
    {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG,i+" -> "+ list_coordinates.get(i).toString());
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You have to set requestExtendedRoutePointsInfo when requesting the route– You have to set requestExtendedRoutePointsInfo when requesting the route – this way you will get the coordinates for all the route points. Here's an example:

```
        SKRouteSettings* route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];
        route.startCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9667, 23.7167);
        route.destinationCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9677, 23.7567);
        route.shouldBeRendered = YES; // If NO, the route will not be rendered.
        route.requestAdvices = YES;
        route.numberOfRoutes = 1;
        route.requestExtendedRoutePointsInfo = YES;
        [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRoute:route];
```

Comment: My app is on android and not on iOS. I use your settings but the function returns alist of 30 items with lon=0 and lat=0.

Comment: I edited the answer cause i think it's important anyone else want to know the java approach.